On Microsoft Power BI, Polygon data type in map
our software has a polygon data type that contains shapes showing forest houses on the map. They are usually rectangular in shape. We keep this data in a Postgresql database, I want to be able to present it as a report. Is it possible to do this on powerbi? After a long research, I can only use Point type maps with X Y coordinates.

By converting the Polygon data type to X Y, I was able to obtain the coordinates and mark them on the map, but I want to show special drawings.
